# Can I use chromatography to compare the amounts of chlorophyll in different leaves?

Tags: chromatography

I have been unable to find a clear answer online about the effect that concentration of a solute has on the retention factor.

If it is as I suspect, I should see plants with more chlorophyll having higher retention factors for chlorophyll. Is this true, and if not, what is the relationship?

Sorry if this is a terrible question, thanks for the help!

Feel free to correct my question, I'm not very familiar with chromatography.

Comment: Retention refers to the system stationary phase / eluent / eluate(s) not to the ability of your leaves to contain chlorophyll. In principle you can. Most of the work will be the quantitative extraction of C. from the leaves and doing so in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the concentration of the analyte does not affect its retention factor in chromatography. That is the entire idea of having a constant retention factor: that you can immediately identify a compound based on where on the TLC/chromatogram it turns up.

In practice, very high amounts can lead to overloading which in turn leads to tailing. Each column or TLC plate has a certain capacity up to which the compound will travel normally and after which it will no longer. The top of the analyte will still reach the same position but it will draw a lengthy tail behind it. However, this typically happens way above the detection limit so you can half your sample size without any problems. (For liquid or gas chromatography, this might even be required because otherwise you may have left the linear region of the sensor.)